# Why do my WebAPI RESTful routes throw 404 errors?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-web-api

On a side-project I am working on, I am creating a RESTful API using WebAPI 2.2.  The thing I'm working on is a means of accessing settings for a game.  An example of the kind of routes I am trying to accomplish are as follows:

```
http://x/api/GameSettings/             <-- Returns all settings
http://x/api/GameSettings/audio        <-- Returns the 'audio' category
http://x/api/GameSettings/audio/volume <-- Returns the key 'volume' in category audio
```

Note: the examples are all `Get` requests.

I've implemented the following controller...

```
public class GameSettingsController : ApiController
{
    // GET /api/GameSettings
    public HttpResponseMessage Get()
    {
        // Magic
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, model);
    }

    public HttpResponseMessage Get(string category)
    {
        // Similar.
    }

    public HttpResponseMessage Get(string category, string key)
    {
        // Slightly different, but still similar.
    }
}
```

I bound up the following MVC routes:

```
// Only necessary for the main view...
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
);
```

And, I bound up the following WebAPI routes:

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "ApiGeneralCommand",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}",
    defaults: new { controller = "GameSettings" }
);

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "ApiCategoryCommands",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{category})",
    defaults: new { controller = "GameSettings" }
);

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "ApiKeyCommands",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{category}/{key}",
    defaults: new { controller = "GameSettings", category = "master" },
    constraints: new { key = "[a-z0-9.-]" }
);
```

...And finally, my `Global.asax` configuration is set up like so:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
}
```

...But one small problem.

When I navigate to `http://x/api/GameSettings/audio`, I get a 404 error.  It's as if the `category` argument in the request isn't being properly associated to the `Get(string category)` method on my controller.  This leads me to believe my routes are wrong or I'm missing something.

As a sanity check, I tested the route using a non-RESTful syntax, `http://x/api/GameSettings?category=audio`, which hit a breakpoint and yielded a result.  This only reaffirms my theory that the WebAPI routing is off.

As an additional sanity check, I tested `http://x/api/GameSettings/` and not only hit a breakpoint set in that function, but returned the expected result.

**Question:** What is my routing missing, that will allow `http://x/api/GameSettings/audio` to work like `http://x/api/GameSettings?category=audio`?  I haven't worked with a RESTful API in a while, so I'm sure I'm missing something really dumb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try to use the attribute routing. I believe that should work well for your scenario.

```
[RoutePrefix("api/GameSettings")]
public class GameSettingsController
{
    // GET /api/GameSettings
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get()
    {
        // Magic
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, model);
    }

    [Route("{category}")]
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get(string category)
    {
        // Similar.
    }

    [Route("{category}/{key}")]
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get(string category, string key)
    {
        // Slightly different, but still similar.
    }
}
```

I would remove the stuff that you have added to the config.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I didn't know this was a thing!  More useful information.  I need to implement APIs more often.  However, this is making a 404 appear for *everything*, including the `/api/GameSettings` path.  Is there any additional configuration necessary for this to work?

Comment: I would look here for more information: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2
It is very useful and easy to use, configure. What are you doing to call these that you are getting a 404? Also, after your refactor, what does your api route config file look like?

Comment: Your post wasn't terribly helpful as to what I'm missing.  I'm running the project, which opens my `Home/Index` page.  To test my API, I manually enter `http://localhost:port/api/GameSettings`.  Upon pressing Enter, what should happen (in IE at least), is a .json file gets downloaded from the server.  After refactoring, all that's left in the `WebApiConfig.Register(HttpConfiguration)` method is `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();`

Comment: Do you have MVC in your project as well? If so, I've found that they ApiRoute config has to be called before the mvc route config

Comment: I've added my Global.asax file to the original question.  Does this look as you're expecting?

Comment: Sorry, also, add [HttpGet] attribute onto each method as well, i.e. [HttpGet]public HttpResponseMessage Get(){...}
Put that attribute on all three methods

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75851/discussion-between-peinearydevelopment-and-andrew-gray).

Comment: Based on the url you posted, are you using IIS express? If so, I think you will need to have the project running to be able to go to that url.

Comment: I think your issue is probably this, you need public class GameSettingsController : ApiController

Comment: The lack of `: ApiController` is a typo - thanks for pointing it out though

Answer (score 2):

Change the order and try.Because ASP.NET realizes that you have three routes.  It will check the top-most route first and if your data can be placed in that route it will not check any more routes.

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "ApiKeyCommands",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{category}/{key}",
        defaults: new { controller = "GameSettings", category = "master" },
        constraints: new { key = "[a-z0-9.-]" }
    ); 

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "ApiCategoryCommands",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{category})",
        defaults: new { controller = "GameSettings" }
    );

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "ApiGeneralCommand",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}",
        defaults: new { controller = "GameSettings" }
    );
```

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work; I'm still getting 404s when I attempt `http://x/api/GameSettings/audio`.  I'm probably missing something else, but this is great info, I'd forgotten it was a priority system.